# Error while cloning a git branch into empty folder

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch

I'm trying to clone a single branch from one of my repo's into a specific folder, but I am getting an unexpected error.

The command I'm using is

```
git clone -b my-branch git@git.myrepoaddress.io:dev/myrepo.git Users/me/Desktop/some_empty_folder
```

However, when I try this I get an error:

### some_empty_folder already exists, and it is not empty

However, it is empty. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you have an invisible file in such folders. You need to activate the option to see hidden files and folders. Or delete the folder and create it again, then it should be completely empty.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I tried that but it didn't work. I used "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES", but there was no hidden files. Tried deleting and re-creating the folder as well.

Comment: Check with `ls -a`, even a `.DS_Store` file can make problems with cloning

Comment: FWIW, `ls -A` would show files whose names begin with a period but hide two standard such names, `.` and `..`.